# все значения равны NaN

Tags: dataframe, kaggle

при считывании некоторых датасетов у меня происходит проблема с данными, все значения равны NaN. например, на train датасете титаника, хотя на большинстве датасетов этого не происходит. в чем может заключаться ошибка?
`titanic = pd.read_csv('train.csv') titanic` [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный разделитель колонок, если я правильно помню, это `;` (или он автоматически как-то определяется, точно не помню). У вас в данных, судя по скриншоту, разделитель запятая. Надо указать это при чтении файла:

```
titanic = pd.read_csv('train.csv', sep=',')
```

Хотя странно, что названия колонок у вас при этом нормально разделились. Хотелось бы увидеть первые пару строчек исходного файла `train.csv`, чтобы дать точный диагноз.

Вообще у вас какой-то кривой файл, похоже, первый же нагугленный аналогичный файл нормально читается стандартным образом:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/agconti/kaggle-titanic/master/data/train.csv')
```

Первые несколько строк нормально читаемого файла `train.csv`:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
```

Comment: я пробовал и sep, и encoding, ничего не помогло, к сожалению

Comment: Ещё я помню с кавычками бывали какие-то проблемы. В общем, надо смотреть исходный файл, чтобы точно сказать, как его правильно читать.

Comment: Попробуйте прочитать файл по приведённой мной ссылке. По результатам можно дальше будет думать.

Comment: по вашей ссылке всё читается нормально, видимо мой файл кривой https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=10557D84B89CB066!843&authkey=!AErVRWxjat9eUHM

Comment: По вашей ссылке файл выглядит нормально, так же как по моей ссылке - с запятыми, но сохраняется он в формате `.xlsx`, поэтому каким был исходный `.csv` файл я не могу так определить.